# Fill in tspan not changing text color

Tags: svg

I have created a simple SVG, where I want to add a link inside a text.
To show that it is a link, I want it to be in the traditional blue with underline.

According to W3 this should be done by tspan with text-decoration="underline" and fill="blue", but this only creates a blue underline and the text-color is unaffected. What am I doing wrong?

Code:

```html
<svg height="500" width="500">
  <rect x="5" y="5" width="490" height="490" fill="#95B3D7"></rect>
  <rect x="20" y="20" width="110" height="23" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#000000"></rect>
  <text x="25" y="25" dominant-baseline="hanging">
    Hi, 
    <tspan text-decoration="underline" fill="blue">
      <a href="https://www.google.com">
        this is a link
      </a>
    </tspan>
  </text>
</svg>
```

EDIT:
Something is very strange here... the code snippet area shows the correct blue text, but when I use the code locally or in jsfiddle, it shows the text in black

Comment: You may have a CSS roule that is overwriting the presentational atribute

Comment: I'm not sure having an `a` tag in an SVG is supported everywhere.

Comment: @robinsax according to https://www.w3.org/wiki/SVG_Links it is, though I should put xlink:href instead of just href... doesn't change the issue!

Comment: Huh, TIL. I agree with @enxaneta, a CSS style targeting `a` is probably the problem

Comment: @robinsax chrome dev-tools doesn't show any css style for <a>. This happens, even if I copy the code in a blank file and open it direktly... no css involved besides chrome default.

Comment: putting text-decoration="underline" fill="blue" directly inside the <a> fixed the problem though...